# Hibernate ConstraintValidation while running Junit

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, junit4

I am working on an enhancement to create a new Table A and reference the id of that as a new column in an existing Table B

I have omitted the entire entity class for brevity.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.apache.bval.constraints.NotEmpty;    
public class TableB implements Serializable {
    --
    @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        @Column(name = "ContactReasonID")
        private Integer contactReasonID;
    ---
    }
```

My Junit Test method is listed below

```
@Test
public void testUpdateInteraction(){
    try {
        interactionService.updateTableB(228, 2, 2642, "test");
        assertTrue(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(false);
    }       
}
```

The parameters for updateTableB are all referring to the old columns.
But when I run the test case I am getting a ConstraintViolationException as shown below

```
[ConstraintViolationImpl{rootBean=net.ashwin.entity.TableB@174d3343, propertyPath='contactReasonID', message='may not be null', leafBean=net.ashwin.entity.TableB@174d3343, value=null}]
```

But the contactReasonID is a nullable column. I am baffled as to where the constraint is.

Environment details:

```
 <spring-framework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>                 <spring-data-jpa>1.4.4.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa>
    <hibernate-framework.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate-framework.version>
```

Any pointers or guidance would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `@NotNull` constraint. Try removing that.

Comment: Wow something so obvious I missed. Always good to have an extra pair of eyes. Thanks @Ish